# How is this mathematical concept "NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)) + NewMin" called?

Tags: math-software

I'm doing some code and I had to map a value from one range [OldMin, OldMax] to another [NewMin, NewMax].

I came across with this answer:

newValue = (((oldValue - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMin

I would like to know how is this mathematical concept called, some sources says it's called "Linear interpolation" others says this is "Linear convertion", but nothing clear.
And also I am curious about who found this concept and its mathematical proof.

Thank you so much.